# multiple room migration causes an error in android

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I need to migrate the Database version 5 to 6, 6 to 7 and vice versa.

So what I did is.

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, MainDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME)
    .addMigrations(
        MIGRATION_7_6,
        MIGRATION_6_5,
        MIGRATION_5_6,
        MIGRATION_6_7)
    .build()
```

The migration between 5 and 6 was fine. And now I am implementing between 6 and 7.

Here's MIGRATIONs

```
val MIGRATION_6_7 = object : Migration(6, 7) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ResultConfig(seq INTEGER NOT NULL, json_data TEXT NOT NULL, updated_at TEXT NOT NULL, created_at TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(seq))")
    }
}

val MIGRATION_7_6 = object : Migration(7, 6) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE ResultConfig")
    }
}
```

```
@Parcelize
@Keep
@Entity(tableName = "result_config")
data class ResultConfig(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val seq: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "json_data") var jsonData: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "updated_at") var updatedAt: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at") var createdAt: String
) : Parcelable {
}
```

And here's the error.

```
Expected:
    TableInfo{name='result_config', columns={created_at=Column{name='created_at', type='TEXT',
affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
defaultValue='null'}, updated_at=Column{name='updated_at',
type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
defaultValue='null'}, seq=Column{name='seq', type='INTEGER',
affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1,
defaultValue='null'}, json_data=Column{name='json_data', type='TEXT',
affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
Found:
    TableInfo{name='result_config', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

I think the table hasn't created properly.

But the database class is like this:

```
@Database(entities = [A::class, B::class, ResultConfig::class], version = 7, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MainDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    // TODO:
}
```

So, the current version is 7. And older version is 6.

What's the problem?

#### UPDATE

I found the problem and it causes because of MIGRATION_6_7.
This line.

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ResultConfig(seq INTEGER NOT NULL, json_data TEXT NOT NULL, updated_at TEXT NOT NULL, created_at TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(seq))")
```

However, when I try this line, it worked.

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `remote_config`(seq INTEGER NOT NULL, json_data TEXT NOT NULL, updated_at TEXT NOT NULL, created_at TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(seq))")
```

But I really want to use the annotation -
@Entity(tableName = "result_config") in the Entity class for integrity. How can I solve and achieve it?

Answer (score -1):

Hum... your code is weird. You don't need to provide a 'downgrade migration' because you must always increase the DB version. Instead, in case of downgrade, it's better to flush the DB with the `fallback` method

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, MainDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME)
    .addMigrations(
        MIGRATION_5_6,
        MIGRATION_6_7)
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigrationOnDowngrade()
    .build()
```

Comment: I need them because sometimes I need to check older versions(Especially, while debugging I need to go back and forth. The reason is the device is not a personal phone but a device in a shop and each devices has its own config data.). And fallbackToDestructiveMigrationOnDowngrade will re-create the database which is not my intention. I need to keep the data.

Comment: And even though I only add MIGRATION_6_7 & fallbackToDestructiveMigrationOnDowngrade(), It doesn't work. And it's the same  problem.